# Django Model DateField and input fixture

Tags: django, django-models, fixtures, loaddata

Model file includes :

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.DateTimeField()
```

Fixture file.json includes:

```
  {
  "model": "app.Foo",
  "pk": "1",
  "fields": {
      "bar": "2018/4/20",
  }
},
```

when I'm trying to add fixtures with "python manage.py loaddata" result is:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 
'C:\Projects\TestProject\app\fixtures\file.json': ['“2018/4/20” value has an 
invalid format. It must be in Y
YYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']: (app.Foo:pk=1) field_value was '2018/4/20'
```

so my question is how can I add date format with "YYYY/MM/DD" to my Model files ?

Comment: you can use `DateField` doc link: `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield`

Comment: Same problem , with models.Datefield

Comment: Can you chnage Date format to this : YYY-MM-DD in your json file?

Comment: No , my task requires this input for me

Comment: What you want isn't possible, because the `models.DateField` and `models.DateTimeField` parse data in a fixed way which isn't dependent on input forms (the corresponding `forms.DateField` **does take into account input formats**). Django **always** uses ISO format for dates and times (like any database). So you would need to either change the way you load the fixtures (pre-parse them with a function that parses the data and returns ISO formatted dates) or write your own DateField.

Comment: @dirkgroten is it possible way to override the methods of loaddata when saving and add some functionality in there ? something like override .save method in models ?

Comment: yes, see my answer: write your own management command.

Answer (score 0):

your using DateTimeField() and your getting  data is only date that's why it's getting the  error instead of DateTimeField() use DateField() 
for example:`class Foo(models.Model):
                bar = models.DateField()`

Comment: I already changed my Model field to DateField and executed with makemigrations and migrare command but the result error changed to : ['“2018/04/20” value has an invalid date format. It must b
e in YYYY-MM-DD format.'] diffrent is removed HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] from error

Comment: the problem isn't just the date, it's the separator format (/ instead of -).

Comment: in settings.py file  add this DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [ '%y/%m/%d'] and change your modal filed name bar = models.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS) it will work

Comment: `input_formats` is an option of **form** fields not on [**model** fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Comment: or get data in 2018-04-20 this format  (or) in settings.py add  DATE_FORMAT = "Y/m/d" and USE_L10N = False

Answer (score 0):

The Django `models.DateField` and `models.DateTimeField` expect input either as python `datetime` objects or in ISO format (with `"-"` separators, not `"/"` separators). This is not something you can easily change because it is also what is used to save the values in the database. So what you want isn't possible.

The only option I see is that you [write your own management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) that first parses your json fixture, changing the dates format to ISO and saving to a new file, then calling the `loaddata` command from within your own `handle()` method.

Note: The corresponding **form fields**, `forms.DateField`, are flexible and accept various input formats and allow you to specify which input format you want to use. In fact, if you enable `i18n` then they will accept international input formats like `2020/03/12`. But that doesn't really help you with `loaddata` which doesn't use a form at all.